# in spring webflux how do I alter the context for a retry?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, retrywhen

I have a reactor chain configured which I would like to retry on failure - I can do this however I am not able to change the context so that the chain knows when it is in a retry.

In the below example I would like for the FLAG value to be "altered" (in deferContextual) during a retry.

```
const val FLAG = "Flag"

fun main() {

    val tr = TestRetry()
    tr.main()
}

class TestRetry {

    fun main() {
        Mono.deferContextual { ctx ->
            val flag = ctx.get<Any>(FLAG)
            println("flag ${flag}")
            Mono.just("hello")
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .map {
            println("map: $it")
            if (true) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }
            "there"
        }
        .retryWhen(retrySpec())
        .contextWrite {
            println("CONTEXT WRITE initialising FLAG")
            it.put(FLAG, "original")
        }
        .subscribe()

        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }

    fun retrySpec(): RetrySpec =
        Retry.max(2L)
            .doBeforeRetry {
                val ctx = it.retryContextView()
                val flag = ctx.getOrDefault(FLAG, "oops") // NOTE: here FLAG is altered
                println ("DO BEFORE RETRY Flag ${flag}")
            }
            .filter { throwable ->
                throwable is IllegalArgumentException
            }
            .onRetryExhaustedThrow { _, retrySignal ->
                println("retries exhausted")
                throw RuntimeException("done")
            }.withRetryContext(
                Context.of(FLAG, "altered")
            )
}
```

When running the above example I am trying to change the value of the FLAG variable in the `withRetryContext`, and I can see that in `doBeforeRetry` the value has changed, however when we get back to `Mono.deferContextual` the value is back to "original". I don't think I correctly understand how the reactor code works.